# gnuPG encrypt and decrypt compress commands

Tags: security, gnupg

I used this command to compress and encrypt a directory:

```
tar zcvf - /tmp/directory | gpg -c > /tmp/directory.tar.gz.gpg
```

Do you think this is a logical command. Could you suggest a better one and the corispoding dycript command you would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
gpg --decrypt /tmp/directory.tar.gz.gpg | tar xzvf -
```

Comment: I did kinda screw up because after tbe first commad and second it created the whole directory string again under /home/my_usernam ,but it dix the job.